# foo(:bar) if foo(:bar) != 0 the rails-way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have this if-condition:

```
foo(:bar) if foo(:bar) != 0
```

and I asked myself if there is a better "rails-/ruby-way" to express this condition? (Without calling the foo(:bar) twice?)

Comment: You need to provide the context where you're calling this. At first I thought you wanted to make a method call if some condition was met, but you're calling that same method to check the condition `:)`, so please, provide more info about this

Comment: i imagine the condition is just an example. take this one instead `foo(:bar) if ['x','y'].member?(foo(:bar))`. that is, run the method if the return value is part of some collection. in general, its give me the return value of this method if the return value meets some condition.

Comment: thx for all the answers, but why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your example is a pretty normal way of doing it. as @ndn said, you can assign to a variable if your method foo is either not performant or very verbose, and as a result inconvenient to call twice.

```
baz if (baz = foo(:bar)) != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to do it without referencing `foo(:bar)` twice. Ruby has ways of handling a `nil` response and substituting another value but not a zero value.

```
foo(:bar) unless foo(:bar).zero?

foo(:bar).zero? ? nil : foo(:bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[foo(:bar)].find{ |x| x.nonzero? }
```

of course in the general case, you can use any other predicate you wish instead of `x.nonzero?`

In the case given in the question, you can write even more simply

```
[foo(:baz)].find(&:nonzero?)
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve. When I read your comment, it occurred to me that I don't need the `x` variable for this case.

Answer (score 0):

So you wish to call a function only if the result of that function is not 0. This means you must call the function anyway to check it's result, so just:

```
foo(:bar)
```

This is without context, if you provide some context for where you use this, i'm sure we could provide better options.